# using (+) after where statement in sql server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

How can i convert following plsql to tsql. `B.STATUS(+)=1` doesnt work in tsql.

```
  Select * from A,B where A.ID=B.ID(+)
     WHERE B.STATUS(+)=1
```

this doesnt return rows in mssql because it doesnt understand B.STATUS is optional

```
 Select * from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID
WHERE B.STATUS=1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An OUTER JOIN changes to an INNER JOIN when a condition is applied to the outer table in the WHERE clause. In the ON clause, it stays as OUTER.

You need to push the predicate "in"

```
 Select * from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.STATUS=1
```

OR

```
 Select * from
     A LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.STATUS=1) B1 ON A.ID = B1.ID
```

Comment: Select * from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.STATUS=1 this doesnt return rows if B table doesnt have records

Comment: @mcb: have you tried it? It *will* return rows from A whether there are rows in B or not. Common sql technique that isn't SQL Server specific: here pl/sql is the odd one out.

Comment: Select * from
     A LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.STATUS=1) B1 ON A.ID = B1.ID works but i dont want to use "SELECT * FROM B" cause of performance optimization.When i use Select * from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.STATUS=1,it doesnt understand that B.STATUS optional.So it tries to filter B.STATUS=1 although there is no records in B Table.

Comment: @mcb: sorry, but you are 2nd guessing SQL Server's optimiser when you don't *know* SQL Server or T-SQL. The queries are the same: the 2nd one adds readability. Unless you can prove me wrong of course...

Comment: ok gbn.Thanks for ur help.I will  use (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.STATUS=1).u are right that i am not good at Optimization.After i looked explain plan,i see there is no difference as performance.But be sure that ur first query doesnt  return rows if B.Doesnt have records.Before i asked question here,i tried ur first query but it didnt work.Thanks again for ur help

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Rolled back and explained further.

Comment: No problem.  A possibly better way of explaining it is that the filter conditions in the ON clause are applied under the rules of OUTER JOIN, but filter conditions in the (main) WHERE clause are applied after the results of the OUTER JOIN have been established.  If the WHERE clause condition eliminates a row, it stays eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it an OR "(b.status = 1 OR b.status IS NULL)"